# How to start spring-boot app without depending on username and password for Database oracle?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, oracle19c

I'm using oracle database 19c and spring boot jpa and for authentification i'm using jwt.As part of which I have a requirement where my sprint-boot app should be able to start even when i don't put the username and password in my config.proprities.
It should get the username and password when the user authenticate in front end and send his username and password to API .
//My config.proprities

```
 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl

jasypt.encryptor.password=aLPa@@sToRm++
```

Comment: Why should the username/password being used for the DB connection be the same as the one supplied? You state you are using JWT and not username/password?

Comment: For security reasons we must not put the username and password in the API, once the user tries to connect in the front end part we use this same username and password for connect with the database, we are looking for a dynamic authentication and not a static one. Execuse me for my bad english

Comment: So all of your application users are also DB users? And with that I don't mean entries in the table `user` for your application but real users as created on the DB.

Comment: Yes , the real users are creating on the DB.